# When $\sigma$-algebras coincide

Tags: measure-theory

Consider two $\sigma$-algebras: The first one is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}([0,1]^2)$ and the second is the $\sigma$-algebra of $Z = X \times Y = [0,1]^2$ generated by rectangles $A \times B \ $ with $A, B \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$.

I must prove that these two $\sigma$-algebras coincide. I'm trying to understand how to tackle this question. I know that $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$ but how is this different than the "coincide" part?

I'm sorry if this question isn't very clear, but the book I'm using (Bartle) does not seem to bring much on this subject.

Comment: $\mathcal B(\mathbb R) \times \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$. There is no equality.

Comment: The proof for your problem is similar to the one dimensional case. E.g $\{[a,b] \mid a\leq b\}$ generates $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @AlvinL ... that depends on your textbook.  Sometimes $\times$ is used for the product sigma-algebra.

Comment: @GEdgar  Overloaded notation when talking about rectangles $A\times B$ in the same breath. Bad style, don't like it.

Answer (score 1):

The right equality is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. By definition, the left $\sigma$-field is generated by all open sets in $\mathbb{R^2}$, whereas the right one is generated by the rectangles $A \times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

You may replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any Polish space, like $[0,1]$. The proof of this fact relies on the existence of a countable basis of open sets (which necessarily generate the Borel $\sigma$-field).